# Cannot install unity due to compiz-core-abiversion-20110828

Tags: apt, unity, package-management

I lost my unity 3d, and I want to install it back. But when I want to install it back, it raises this error:

```
utm@utm:~$ sudo apt-get install unity 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity : Depends: compiz-core-abiversion-20110828
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there any way around to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Use `aptitude` to resolve problems, it's better then `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get update && sudo aptitude -f install && sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
sudo aptitude install unity
```

also run this (which'll save you some time in the future). When holding `[Alt]` and typing `ai` inserts `sudo aptitude install` under cursor :-)

```
echo  "\"\\ea\\ei\": \"sudo aptitude install \"" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal for a development version.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Afterwards you should be able to install unity.