# Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04

The top panel and `Unity` launcher have disappeared in Ubuntu 14.04. Also cannot access the terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

 I have tried every solution for this issue that I can find, from re-installing unity and compiz to resetting Unity and everything. I've gone into the compiz manager and reactivated Unity.

Nothing has worked.

When trying to reset Unity, or do anything with it really, I get this message

```
(process:6332): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

**EDIT:**
Installed 14.04 a day ago. The issue happened after a reboot. After installing `virtual Box`

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me. Afraid to attempt re-installing virtualbox. Ever figure out why this happened?

Comment: Running `export DISPLAY=:0` on a separate tty, following the procedure outlined in http://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable and finally running `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` did the trick for me.

Comment: I'm also missing the launcher & menu bar, software-center is uninstalled, and I cannot open a terminal either through Ctrl-Alt-T nor Ctrl-Alt-F1-6.  By booting into single-user mode (rEFInd), I automatically became root (without needing a password).  This allowed me to create a new user and add them to the `sudo` group.  I've now logged into the new account (where the GUI is fine) and have used `su` to get into my original account.  I'm wondering if its possible to copy the GUI setup from the new user to my old one?  If so, what should I copy?

Comment: Same problem after installing Virtual Box... Solution 
`export DISPLAY=:0`    
`sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`
`setsid unity`

Comment: @JanakaBandara how did you run the script in your link? What `source` do I have to specify?

Comment: @ArchStanton Are you referring to `source ./filename.sh` from http://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell ? I can't remember exactly, but probably I just copied and pasted the content in a tty rather than creating a new file to be `source`d :)

Comment: @JanakaBandara Hi! Thanks for the answer. To tell the truth, I don't know what that "source" is meant to be... I solved the problem anyway, by deleting `monitors.xml` in `/home/user_name/.config/`. Happy holydays! :-)

Comment: Same here. Unity disappeared after I had installed virtualbox. @Ashu answer solved the issue for me. Before that however I've also run `sudo apt-get -f upgrade`

Answer (score 46):

Enter the following commands:- `Ctrl+Alt+F1`
login there with username and password

> **WARNING! THE FOLLOWING COMMAND WILL TERMINATE YOUR ACTIVE SESSION!**

try:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

If restarting `lightdm` doesn't fix the problem, install `aptitude` and then install `unity`:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get update && sudo aptitude -f install && sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
sudo aptitude install unity
```

Read the outputs carefully. If you do have broken dependencies, aptitude will give you the "solution" of NOT installing `unity`. Say no to this solution. Then it will give you another solution which will install broken dependencies. Say yes to this one. Once installation is complete,
`sudo service lightdm restart` again. If you still have some issues, also reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

followed by another `sudo service lightdm restart`.

(Credit to [@DinGODzilla](https://askubuntu.com/users/20888/dingodzilla) from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/111338))

Comment: Warning! This terminates the session.

Comment: I read the warning too late, god damn :D

Comment: Same problem as OP, but when I C-A-F1 (-F6) I get a blank screen. (No terminal.)  What other options do I have?

Comment: Ha, ha... Yeah, too late, it terminated my session, though my VPN connection is up. So, it does not free everything.

Comment: Same issue occurred on 16.04 and restarting lightdm  service worked for me.

Comment: Even this solution is also not working for me in 14.04.... help?

Comment: Confirming this worked. The question that remains: what broke it in the first place? For me it was a spontaneous reboot while compiling a program I'm working on.

Comment: @Dror read the warning to late :(

Answer (score 2):

Hold down `Alt-F2`, which will bring up a dialog to enter terminal commands. There, type the command `cinnamon-launcher` and hit enter. That should restore the panel.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue in ubunt 14.04, i fix it by below steps

1. `ctrl+alt+f1`
2. enter username and password
3. run `mv ~/.config ~/.config_backup`
4. run `sudo service lightdm restart`

Hope it will work

Comment: Thank you.  I've been trying things for a while and this is the first one that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with gnome panels. Instead of restarting lightdm which kills the session and closes the apps. I solve the issue by:

1. Minimizing all the apps;
2. Pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del (you might need
   to do it a couple of times);
3. After 2. a popup asking to logout
   appears - close it or it would log you out.

The panels are back again. This trick always helps me when gnome panels disappear.

Comment: Not getting any popup in step 2....?

Comment: Very much depends how your Ctrl-Alt-Del is setup... if it does a restart instead of opening a dialog, you know...