# Ubuntu 14.04 - Error on line 1 char 1

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, configuration, monitor

I have been using `Ubuntu 14.04` for some weeks now dual booted with Vista on a Dell Inspiron laptop. I use a dual monitor set up which was working fine. I unplugged my laptop once from the external monitor and upon restarting in Ubuntu - after logging in - I got the following error message. (I still get the same error if plugging into an external monitor too.)

`Error on line 1 char 1:
Document must begin with an element (e.g. <book>)
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors.`

I have already tried troubleshooting this online and have tried the following:

- `sudo apt-get -f install`
- removing the `~/.config/monitors.xml` file

Neither of which fixed the problem.

The taskbar is not visible and the keyboard doesn't work (CTRL-ALT-T doesn't bring up the terminal for example and CTRL-ALT-TAB doesn't work either). There is no top bar for windows with the buttons to close or minimise/maximise and so the only way to close files is to you CTRL-Q which for some reason still works.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I solved this by using this thread:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-menu-bar-disappeared-in-14-04

Comment: I'm having this exact problem on 16.04 but the answers on https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04 are not working for me