# Lost Menu and Taskbar

Tags: menu

Inadvertently clicked something that removed menu and taskbar in 15.10. None of the solutions that I can find are for recent formats and none, so far have worked. I can get into terminal by right clicking on screen but none of the commands bring back menu. Not all that tech savvy. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Launcher and Menu Bar disappeared in 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-menu-bar-disappeared-in-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

You may have just "hidden" the menu. "Slap" (bounce your cursor into) the mouse (cursor) into the top-left corner of the screen, and see if it pops up / appears.
If it is indeed "lost", someone else more savvy than I may be able to answer this. Good Luck!

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? I can't tell, please edit this to use clear English, many users don't speak much English and would have no idea what this is saying.

Comment: Thanks YourNYTech - about 24 hours after posting my question I managed to retrieve the menu but I'm not sure how. Thank you for coming to assistance - much appreciated.

Comment: You're quite welcome!