# Launcher and menu bar have disappeared on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, package-management, launcher, menu-bar

[image: After login this appears]

Yesterday, I uninstalled several applications. When I rebooted the computer, I found that the launcher and menu bar had disappeared and every function related to them has gone.

I read this post:
[Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-menu-bar-disappeared-in-14-04)

But didn't find a solution.

What should I do?

Comment: It would be good to know what you uninstalled and what changes were made by these processes.
A first step might be to look in /var/log/dpkg.log

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the cause of the problem, this may fix it:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
unity --reset-icon &disown
```

That is sometimes sufficient to restore a functioning desktop in Unity.

Comment: Hello Sir, Its working !!! Thank you very Much :)