# no unity and menubar

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, ccsm

Unity doesn't load and no menubar?

---

update :
I've tried solution from [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

It says I have to enable unity plugin with ccsm. It says "Loading icons".But I am able to enable the plugin and go back to TTY and the ccsm stuck on "Loading icons ...". I go back to my desktop and close the ccsm, "Loading icons..." disappear, but after I reboot, nothing happened. still no menubar and unity.

I also tried https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/437417 but stuck on

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm
```

it diplays nothing after i tried Ctrl+Fn+Alt+F7

I also  tried `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` from https://askubuntu.com/a/290376/437417 , but it says "cannot autolaunch D-bus without X11 $DISPLAY".

I tried `Ctrl+Fn+Alt+F1` `sudo service lightdm restart`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

from https://askubuntu.com/a/476623/437417, nothing happened.

now, what should I do? Please help me ;_;

---

OS : Only Ubuntu 14.04
processor : Intel core i3
graphic cards : AMD Radeon Graphics
Laptop : Lenovo  B40

Comment: Did you install any new software or update/upgrade anything just before this problem appeared?  I assume performance is Ok booting into the login screen (since you were able to get to the guest account)?  Do you use Wi-Fi or eathernet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: Last thing I install was something with code '$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server'. I use it to install app for presentation remote from android. I use wifi. I just find out that I can actually  right-click my desktop, so I guess my computer isn't slow at all.

Answer (score -1):

You could trie this:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: It says "cannot autolaunch D-bus without X11 $DISPLAY"

Comment: Have you tried this: sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession/custom.default and enter this [Default session] NAME=ubuntu EXEC=/etc/X11/x11/Xsession