# Ubuntu 16.04 launcher is missing after installing new updates

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

I upgraded to 16.04 from 15.10 and every things was good. After installing new updates, launcher, menus and top panel disappear when I login.

I tried this commands:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Also used `ccsm` command and checked that Unity plugins is enabled. Still problem exists.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending so much times and searching, I tested almost all the solutions on the internet.

1. [Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login/481620#481620)
2. [Launcher disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656862/launcher-disappeared)
3. [Ubuntu 16.04 no menu bar or launcher - help!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761035/ubuntu-16-04-no-menu-bar-or-launcher-help)

But problem didn't solve. Totally the only solution which worked for me was follwing this instruction:

1. open `/usr/bin/` and run `gnome-terminal.real`
2. run `adduser newuser` to create a new user
3. run `kill -9 -1` to logout
4. login using `newuser`
5. do #1 again
6. run `su olduser` and enter your password
7. run `mv /home/olduser /home/olduser_backup`
8. run `mkdir /home/olduser`
9. run `chown olduser:olduser /home/olduser`
10. run `reboot`
11. login using `olduser`

Totally you can delete `newuser` by running these commands:

```
sudo deluser newuser
sudo rm /home/newuser -rf
```

Answer (score 1):

After updating my Ubuntu 16.04 I experienced the same issue. I solved it by removing the `/home/your_username/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig` directory:

```
rm -rf /home/your_username/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig
```

After which I logged out and in.

The directory originally contained the files:

- `config`
- `Default.ini`
- `done_upgrades`

After removing the directory and logging in and out, it now contains the files:

- `config`
- `done_upgrades`

The `done_upgrades` file has not changed and the `config` file has changed from:

```
[general_ubuntu-lowgfx]
backend = ini
profile = 
integration = true
plugin_list_autosort = true
```

to:

```
[general_ubuntu-lowgfx]
profile = unity-lowgfx
```

The removed `Default.ini` contained:

```
[core]
s0_outputs = 1488x858+0+0;
```

So I guess the issue was caused by one of these files, but I know nothing about compiz, so I cannot tell what could have caused it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this problem when running 16.04 under VirtualBox (like I did) none of these fixes work but changing the machine settings to remove 3D acceleration will bring the unity desktop back.

Comment: I got the problem running 16.04 under VirtualBox, and my solution definitely worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After my recent 16.04 update, I had this same problem.  What finally fied it for me after trying many solutions that did not work:

1. chown user.user ~/.config/dconf/user (change owner and group of user file)
2. kill -9 -1  (to log outof session)
3. log back in and bar has returned