# Menu Bar and Launcher missing after installing updates (16.04 LTS)

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

I have Ubuntu running in a VirtualBox VM on both a Windows 7 host and also a Macbook Pro.

Four times now (on two different hosts) after having successfully installed (auto-)updates, and restarted the machine, I get my normal desktop background, but no launcher.  I can right-click on the desktop and open up a terminal  The terminal window is fixed to to the top left of the desktop, and has no menubar - despite the context menu (right-click) showing the menubar as being enabled.

Alas, almost everything I have tried to do from within the terminal has had precisely no effect. I have tried each and every suggestion I could find from answers to similar issues - eg.:

- [Ubuntu 16.04 launcher is missing after installing new updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801742/ubuntu-16-04-launcher-is-missing-after-installing-new-updates)

The only thing that works thus far is running "unity --debug".

Any and all suggestions would be most welcome.

many tias,
gary

Answer (score 2):

I found the same thing from updating today. Finally found that in ~/.profile there was a line:

```
export UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE="1"
```

If you press ctrl+n on the desktop it'll show your home folder, then ctrl+h will show hidden files.

Open ~/.profile then remove or comment out `export UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE="1"`.

I also removed my Unity config (I renamed `/home/huw/.config/compiz-1` to `/home/huw/.config/compiz-1-old`)

Then restarted and it was all working. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu under VirtualBox V5.0.24 on macOS 10.11.6   My ~/.profile did not have the export line.  However, the rename of ~/.config/compiz-1 worked for me as well.
I did some experiments and found that just trashing ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config resolved the problems on my setup.  Shortly after trashing that file the menu bar and launcher appeared and a new empty config file was created.  I suspect an empty config file results in the same effect as the config created after renaming compiz-1 which created a new config (works) containing only the following two lines.

```
[general_ubuntu-lowgfx]
profile = unity-lowgfx
```

The old ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config (that didn't work) had the following lines

```
[general_ubuntu-lowgfx]
backend = ini
profile = 
integration = true
plugin_list_autosort = true
```

Answer (score 0):

As solution 0 stated, I did not have that export line in ~/.profile. 
Further, .config/compiz-1 was an empty subdir.
Renaming, or deleting that subdirectory creates a new one. However, selecting autohide to yes, breaks the system....this solution above is a recovery of the launcher, not a fix for autohide.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming or removing `~/.config/compiz-1` worked for me.
Here is what I've done.

- left-click on the desktop's background and choose "Open Terminal"
- At the prompt, type

  ```
  mv .config/compiz-1 .config/compiz-1-old

  sudo reboot
  ```

After the reboot everything worked fine again.