# After updating Ubuntu 16.04 in Virtualbox, only desktop background is visible

Tags: unity, nvidia, 16.04, updates

I updated Ubuntu 16.04 in Virtualbox on Windows 7 and now I can only get the desktop background.

I found these questions:

[Ubuntu 16.04 launcher is missing after installing new updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801742/ubuntu-16-04-launcher-is-missing-after-installing-new-updates)

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[GUI disappeared since last update, Ubuntu 16.04 running in VM on MacOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804011/gui-disappeared-since-last-update-ubuntu-16-04-running-in-vm-on-macos)

[Menu Bar and Launcher missing after installing updates (16.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802468/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-after-installing-updates-16-04-lts)

I tried a lot of things all without success, then I tried the steps in https://askubuntu.com/a/801782/574037, getting as far as step 7 before getting an "permission denied" error.

Please help - I'm almost out of ideas.

I have a Nvidia card, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I also run Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox on top of Windows 7 and had the same problem. To me the solution was to "Enable 3D Acceleration" in the Virtual Machine Settings. (I can reproduce the problem still if I disable that setting.)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Ubuntu 15.10 Host, 16.04 guest.