# Unity doesn't work after upgrading 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and when I restarted it I didn't have a sidebar nor a top-bar, yet in the login page there was a top-bar. All windows opened are only closed using alt+f4. and Ctrl+Alt+T doesn't work. I can open the terminal using mouse right-click or alt+ctrl+f1.

I have tried these following answers but they didn't solve my problem:
[Ubuntu 16.04 launcher is missing after installing new updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801742/ubuntu-16-04-launcher-is-missing-after-installing-new-updates/) ,
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/)

I managed to figure that unity isn't installed. so I tried:
    sudo apt-get install unity
This resulted in the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity : Depends: libunity-core-6.0-9 (= 7.4.0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) but 7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: compiz but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: compiz-plugins-default but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: session-shortcuts but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I couldn't manage to get past the installation of Unity.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. Did you upgrade from another desktop environment than Unity ? That could be the issue.

Comment: I don't know which desktop environment I had before the upgrade.

Comment: Try reinstalling Unity 7.

Comment: should i just write: sudo apt-get install unity7 ?

Comment: I am not sure of the command. Try Google. That is how I fixed it.

Comment: I installed unity8 but i still couldn't install unity itself. same errors as before. or is there a command to run unity8?

Comment: For now, install Gnome and use it. From there you can try some solution. Unity 8 is not ready yet for 16.04. You should go for Unity 7.

Comment: Can you add the content of your `sources.list`  here http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I opened the sources.list file using vi:
http://pastebin.com/raw/0aBhxnAC

Comment: There is a complete `sources.list` : http://pastebin.com/UKxYyueK , i have copied it from ask ubuntu a few days ago to solve a problem

Comment: "I finally managed to solve the problem. I've run the command sudo remove cheese" and afterwards "sudo apt-get install -f" and the I installed unity and it worked.