# Can anyone help me find and install beta amd driver?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, amd-processor

I have amd kaveri 7850k chipset, there is a beta driver but having problems finding it can anyone link it and explain how to install it?

*Ubuntu 16.04 is my OS

Comment: There are two right on AMDs website http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Beta-Driver-for-Vulkan-Release-Notes.aspx and http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx Are these what you are looking for?

Comment: Beta driver? The open source driver included in 16.04 should work fine for graphics. AMD have not released a beta version of the GPU Pro drivers for 16.04 yet. The microcode firmware is for some CPU features I think, and not for the GPU.

Comment: Thanks the link worked, also Beta driver is there for GPUs and APUs

Comment: Now I need to install it, any help?

Comment: What link did you use of the two?

Comment: Second one: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Beta-Driver-for-Vulkan-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: I am going to try a do an answer for you but I don't have AMD so I can't test it and if you face issues, I may not be able to fix them but we can try.

Comment: Also read this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a temporary directory in your /home folder

```
mkdir ~/tmp
```

[Download the driver here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Beta-Driver-for-Vulkan-Release-Notes.aspx) and put it in that directory

Now extract it

```
cd ~/tmp 
tar -xf amdgpu-pro_16.20.3-294842.tar.xz
```

Change to the extracted directory

```
cd amdgpu-pro-driver
```

Now run the install script

```
./amdgpu-pro-install
```

Follow any instructions given and this will install the driver.

Ensure that your user account is a member of the "video" group prior to using the vulkan driver. You can find which groups you are a member of with the following command:

```
groups
```

To add yourself to the video group you will need the sudo password and can use the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```

You will need to log out and in again to activate this change.

That should be it, reboot and you will be using the beta driver.

You can delete the ~/tmp folder we created in the first step.

If for any reason you wish to remove the AMD GPU-PRO graphics stack you can do this using the uninstallation script which was part of the installation and is present in your path. From the command prompt enter the following command:

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

[Source](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx)

Comment: Don't accept the answer if it does not work, I have thousands of rep, I care more about it being right that getting rep.

Comment: It installed, but after login and password the screen is just the background image, I do have access to terminal with right click what can I do next

Comment: Try the solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04 seems like your computer is working but Unity did not load correctly. As the drivers are only beta, they may never work very well.

Comment: Ok, hey does installing gnome shell might work what do u think

Comment: I don't know, you can try, it won't hurt and Unity can be temperamental at times. Did that solution for fixing Unity not work?

Comment: Trying it, need to reboot into ubuntu thanks for everything

Comment: everything worked except this command `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME `

Comment: How did it not work? What happend? There won't be any output. @Pablo

Comment: couldn't make the group video, retried and its a mess wont recommend to try the driver