# Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04 some suggested solutin does not work

Tags: 14.04, unity

I tried the suggested solutions [Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04) and [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/76951#76951), but still I am not able to get the launcher. What else I can do. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you restart `lightdm`?

Comment: Yes I did, but its not working.

Comment: Did you get any error/warning after restarting `lightdm` service?

Comment: I am not getting any error. every thing is executing fine as per suggested solutions  but when I am rebooting the system then not getting the launcher .

Comment: Try this: `$ mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old` and then resart

Comment: I did still no change.

Comment: Try Running this:    
1. `sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`  

2. `setsid unity`  

3. `unity --reset-icons`

Comment: .config/dconf/user can not be successfully moved or removed within an active session unless one does a hard shutdown immediately afterwards  . It will be re-created from memory otherwise. Better to do so from a tty & then a reboot from that tty. The dconf reset may work unless the unity plugin has been disabled. If that's the case then re-enable it.