# How to reinstall gnome classic clock in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, menu-bar

I had a problem with my menu-bar clock and date after some wrong fiddling the clock disappeared. I couldn't figure out how to reinstall it. 
I did see receive some suggestions, but none of them worked and after I tried them it got worse: the menu-bar disappeared completely!

One of the suggestions is "You need to reset the per-user configuration of the notification area." by  David Foerster. I would like to know how to do it. BTW, I am using Gnome Classic.

Comment: Reinstalling won't help. You need to reset the per-user configuration of the notification area.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to change your question, clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check clock settings and make sure you mark up `show a clock in the menu bar` option.

[image]

If it not editable or responsive then follow this steps .

First make sure your Ubuntu is Upgraded

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then reinstall `gnome-control-center`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

then restart the task bar service by

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

Comment: What does Unity have to do with GNOME Classic? Also, while this may answer the literal question, the question wrongly assumes that a package reinstallation will solve the underlying issue. See my comment on the question.

Comment: I had had the same problem and this commands solved it !

Comment: I tried and now my menu bar diappeared completely. Any suggestions?

Comment: sudo service lightdm restart

Comment: all what the commands do is reinstalling gnome control center ,sure you did some thing wrong

Comment: you asked how to reinstall and i tolled you what i did when the same problem face me . and it works for me

Comment: this may help you .
https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04

Comment: @MahmoudS.Marwad: Again, what does Unity have to do with the GNOME Classic desktop that OP uses?