# Black 'X' instead of cursor, no tool bar nor full windows

Tags: 16.04

I use Ubuntu 16.04  and everything had been working fine until I logged in yesterday. I restarted my dell laptop several times but nothing changed. First difference which I spotted is the lack of ubuntu logo while my device is activating. Then I am able to see only desktop and its files. There is no toolbar, time etc. Also instead of normal cursor, I have black X and it's not working 100% properly. Next odd thing is that I can not use any shortcuts. Basically, the only useful thing that I can do is opening terminal by right clicking, but when I do it or run any other program I am unable to see or use its taskbar.

Comment: The following instructions solved the issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this happened, but it seems that you get logged into a minimal session. One frequent cause of this or similar problems that I encountered (though normally with an error message) is that your ran out of disk space. In this case, the solution would be to delete some stuff and re-login or reboot. In Terminal, you can check free space with `df -h` and then look for the percentage for the root file system `/`

You said that nothing changed, but did the system maybe do updates in the background and those were interrupted? Was there any error message on startup or login?

Comment: Only 7% of root storage is used and i do not remember any error messages, there is "booting in insecure mode" communicate, but it was there even before the problem occured. I now realised that after closing laptop opening it and the have to log in, it also looks different but when i click "switch account" then I see normal log in screen but after I log in it's still as bad as I described in topic, same for the guest session.